# upload folder to ipfs using blockfrost

Tags: curl, blockchain, ipfs, cardano

How to upload folder to IPFS using blockfrost.

able to upload a file using the following, but not able to upload a folder

```
curl "https://ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add" \
  -X POST \
  -H "project_id: $PROJECT_ID" \
  -F "file=@./README.md"
```

here is the full [documentation](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/IPFS-Add/paths/%7E1ipfs%7E1add/post)

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To upload a folder to IPFS using Blockfrost, you can compress the folder as a zip or tar file and upload it using the same curl command that you used to upload a file.